# using update with upsert and $all

Tags: mongodb

I cannot manage to get this to work:

```
db.library.update({
  categories: {
    $all: ['/movie/action', '/movie/comedy'],
    $nin: ['/movie/cartoon']
  },
  location: {
    $geoWithin: {
      $centerSphere: [[48.8574946, 2.3476296000000048], 50/6378.1]
    }
  }
},
{
  $setOnInsert: {
      categories: ['/movie/action', '/movie/comedy'],
      location: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [48.8574946, 2.3476296000000048]
      }
  },
  $addToSet: {users: {_id: '1', date: '2018-04-06'}}
},
{ upsert: true })
```

It returns the following error:

```
cannot infer query fields to set, path 'categories' is matched twice
```

I understand that query part is moved to update part when upsert happens, but I'm not sure how to keep `$all` from having this effect

It does work when `$all` array is not set to more than 1 element.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this solution, even though it's painful to be forced to list `$all` elements under `{ $elemMatch: { $eq:...` :

```
db.library.update({
  categories: {
        $all: [
            { $elemMatch: { $eq: '/movie/action' } },
            { $elemMatch: { $eq: '/movie/comedy' } }
        ],
        $nin: ['/movie/cartoon']
  },
  location: {
    $geoWithin: {
      $centerSphere: [[48.8574946, 2.3476296000000048], 50/6378.1]
    }
  }
},
{
  $setOnInsert: {
      categories: ['/movie/action', '/movie/comedy'],
      location: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [48.8574946, 2.3476296000000048]
      }
  },
  $addToSet: {users: {_id: '1', date: '2018-04-06'}}
},
{ upsert: true })
```

any simpler solution is welcome